# How to change foreign key reference table name in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration

I have this line in a migration table

```
Schema::create('xyzTableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('userId');
    $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('userId');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

where I did write **on('userId')** by mistake
what I want is **on('users')**

now I did this, (in a new migration, as I can't run `migrate:fresh`)

```
 Schema::create('xyzTableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->change();
        });
```

but I don't why it is not working, please help me

Comment: please specify what error do you get ? also, you have two arrow here `->->change();`

Comment: I guess the first migration will never run due to an error as the `userId` table will not be found that time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the old key and build a new one

```
Schema::table('xyzTableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('xyzTableName_users_userId_foreign');
    $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Laravel will always try to create the keys using its patterns. Since you didn't follow the name and field pattern recommended by laravel I can't be sure that string 'xyzTableName_users_userId_foreign' will be the correct one.

Check in your database the foreign key name. This is the command I'd use If MySQL

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
    AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
    AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```

[Reference](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-see-foreign-key-relationship-of-a-table.html#:%7E:text=To%20see%20foreign%20key%20relationships%20of%20a%20column%3A,%27%20AND%20REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME%20%3D%20%27column_name%27%3B)

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked. And I checked it, the correct string is `xyztablename_userid_foreign` as Laravel 4.2+ introduces a new naming convention: `<table_name>_<column_name>_foreign` also all small letters